# Avoid "bundle install" to use pre-compiled gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, passenger, bundler

This is my very first question here :)

On a rails 3.2.6 (using rvm and ruby 1.8.7), my Gemfile contains two gems that cause problems when using the `bundle install` command.

Those gems are specified using:

```
gem 'libv8', "~> 3.11.8.3"
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.0beta6'
```

My problem is the following: when running `bundle install` command, bundler fetches binaries (precompiled) gems (libv8-3.11.8.3-x86_64-linux.gem and therubyracer-0.11.0beta6-x86_64-linux.gem) and not the plain source ones (libv8-3.11.8.3.gem and therubyracer-0.11.0beta6.gem).

The x86_64 version is incompatible with my server setup: included dynamic library uses an unknown symbol (rb_intern2, out of my old memory, I could be wrong) that makes that the precompiled gems cant be loaded by the application.

So that I *must* install gem from the source packages.

At the moment, I have to `bundle install`, then remove the precompiled gems from my `~/.rvm/gems/...` and then `gem install ~/tmp/libv8-3.11.8.3.gem` and `gem install ~/tmp/therubyracer-0.11.0beta6.gem`, which is not very practical.

Is there any way to force Bundler to fetch the sources release and compile them ?

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading your ruby, `1.8.7` is no more maintained, the current version is `1.9.3-p194` - and it is what you should be using.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
bundle install --without x86_64-linux
```

`x86_64-linux` is a platform and bundler/rubygems uses it.

It should be equivalent of:

```
gem install libv8 -​-platform ruby
```

Details:

- http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html
- http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install